# Utilizing a Generic class inside a method that receives a generic as parameter

Tags: java, generics, reflection

don't know how to do this, but is there any way to do something like this

```
public class Service<T>{

    public T save(T object){
        //GenericDao is a generic class
        GenericDao<object.class> gdao = new GenericDao<>();
        gdao.persist(object);
        //do some stuffs
    }
}
```

I want pass the class type of the object to instantiate a generic class

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do here.  If GenericDao is so generic that it can take arguments of type Object, then there's no need for it to use Java generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GenericDao<T>` instead of `GenericDao<object.class>`.

Comment: this simple? I will try, thanks, dammit I'm so stupid, worked.